# By using functional programming javascript with folktale2, how to access results of previous tasks gracefully?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js, folktale, fantasyland

A task has a few steps, if each step's input is only from direct last step, it is easy. However, more often, some steps are depend on not only the direct last step.

I can work out via several ways, but all end up with ugly nested code, I hope anyone could help me to find better ways.

I created the following signIn-like example to demonstrate, the process has 3 steps as below:

1. get database connection (() -> Task Connection)
2. find account (Connection -> Task Account)
3. create token (Connection -> accountId -> Task Token)

**#step3 depends not only on step#2 but also step#1.**

The below are the jest unit tests by using folktale2

```
import {task, of} from 'folktale/concurrency/task'
import {converge} from 'ramda'

const getDbConnection = () =>
    task(({resolve}) => resolve({id: `connection${Math.floor(Math.random()* 100)}`})
)

const findOneAccount = connection =>
    task(({resolve}) => resolve({name:"ron", id: `account-${connection.id}`}))

const createToken = connection => accountId =>
    task(({resolve}) => resolve({accountId, id: `token-${connection.id}-${accountId}`}))

const liftA2 = f => (x, y) => x.map(f).ap(y)

test('attempt#1 pass the output one by one till the step needs: too many passing around', async () => {
    const result = await getDbConnection()
        .chain(conn => findOneAccount(conn).map(account => [conn, account.id])) // pass the connection to next step
        .chain(([conn, userId]) => createToken(conn)(userId))
        .map(x=>x.id)
        .run()
        .promise()

    console.log(result) // token-connection90-account-connection90
})

test('attempt#2 use ramda converge and liftA2: nested ugly', async () => {
    const result = await getDbConnection()
        .chain(converge(
            liftA2(createToken),
            [
                of,
                conn => findOneAccount(conn).map(x=>x.id)
            ]
        ))
        .chain(x=>x)
        .map(x=>x.id)
        .run()
        .promise()

    console.log(result) // token-connection59-account-connection59
})

test('attempt#3 extract shared steps: wrong',  async () => {
    const connection = getDbConnection()

    const accountId = connection
    .chain(conn => findOneAccount(conn))
    .map(result => result.id)

    const result = await of(createToken)
    .ap(connection)
    .ap(accountId)
    .chain(x=>x)
    .map(x=>x.id)
    .run()
    .promise()

    console.log(result) // token-connection53-account-connection34, wrong: get connection twice
})
```

- attempt#1 is right, but I have to pass the output of very early step till the steps need it, if it is across many steps, it is very annoying.
- attempt#2 is right too, but end up with nested code.
- I like attempt#3, it use some variable to hold the value, but unfortunately, it doesn't work.

**Update-1**
I am think another way to put all outputs into a state which will pass through, but it may very similar attempt#1

```
test.only('attempt#4 put all outputs into a state which will pass through',  async () => {
    const result = await getDbConnection()
    .map(x=>({connection: x}))
    .map(({connection}) => ({
        connection,
        account: findOneAccount(connection)
    }))
    .chain(({account, connection})=>
        account.map(x=>x.id)
        .chain(createToken(connection))
    )
    .map(x=>x.id)
    .run()
    .promise()


    console.log(result) //     token-connection75-account-connection75
})
```

**update-2**
By using @Scott's `do` approach, I am pretty satisfied with the below approach. It's short and clean.

```
test.only('attempt#5 use do co', async () => {
    const mdo = require('fantasy-do')

    const app = mdo(function * () {
        const connection = yield getDbConnection()
        const account =  yield findOneAccount(connection)

        return createToken(connection)(account.id).map(x=>x.id)
    })

    const result = await app.run().promise()

    console.log(result)
})
```

Comment: I guess the question is how to access results of previous `task`s, right? Doing this with explicitly passing a state object through the chain isn't that bad. Moreover you could combine `task` with a `readerT` monad transformer (or with `stateT` if you need mutation) to abstract from that object. But I am neither sure if this abstraction is worth the effort, nor if you can implement a proper `readerT` with Javacript's prototype system.

Comment: @ftor, I think I need to learn some haskell to understand `readerT` monad, I guess it may like some centralized state. I will look into `readerT` and `stateT`. thanks a lot for this information.

Comment: Related, if not duplicate of [How do I access previous promise results in a .then() chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28250680/1048572) - while `Task`s are not eager, their monadic interface and `parallel` combination are exactly equivalent to promises.

Comment: @Bergi yeah, it is related. In your question, the answer for promise is `await/async` and `yield`. While in `monad` world, there is no `await/async` language level support, but we still can use `yield` with `fantacy-do` support.

Comment: @ftor, I updated the title to be more clearly, thanks.

Comment: @Ron All the other approaches are detailed in the other answers :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example could be written as follows:

```
const withConnection = connection =>
  findOneAccount(connection)
      .map(x => x.id)
      .chain(createToken(connection))

getDbConnection().chain(withConnection)
```

This is similar to your second attempt, though makes use of `chain` rather than `ap`/`lift` to remove the need for the subsequent `chain(identity)`. This could also be updated to use `converge` if you want, though I feel it loses a great amount of readability in the process.

```
const withConnection = R.converge(R.chain, [
  createToken,
  R.compose(R.map(R.prop('id')), findOneAccount)
])

getDbConnection().chain(withConnection)
```

It could also be updated to look similar to your third attempt with the use of generators. The follow definition of the `Do` function could be replaced by one of the existing libraries that offers some form of "do syntax".

```
// sequentially calls each iteration of the generator with `chain`
const Do = genFunc => {
  const generator = genFunc()
  const cont = arg => {
    const {done, value} = generator.next(arg)
    return done ? value : value.chain(cont)
  }
  return cont()
}

Do(function*() {
  const connection = yield getDbConnection()
  const account = yield findOneAccount(connection)
  return createToken(connection)(account.id)
})
```

Comment: thanks for your input. first code set looks clean but nested, I agreed that the second code set is not very readable. The last sounds good, it like `co` in `promise` world, interesting, though there is no such one existed.

Comment: @Ron I've edited the example to pull the nested continuation out into its own `withConnection` function, though it only superficially reduces the nesting. I've also included a simple implementation of `Do` for you, though there are some existing libraries that already offer this functionality as well like https://github.com/jwoudenberg/fantasy-do and https://github.com/pelotom/burrido

Comment: thanks for your updates. Though I still feel the updated codeset is nested, I do like your  `do` approach with two libraries, it's short and clean, I already updated the passed unit test into my original post.